# workspace global python module - where to put?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to have a python module globally available across all nodes in a catkin workspace. It contains functions that I don't want to repeat in every module I need them. They are pure Python modules. I'd like to do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# mymodule.py

def myFunction(a):
  # just an example
  something = a * 2
  return something

# End of mymodule.py
```

And in my ROS Python scripts I'd like to be able to import that module like...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import roslib...
import mymodule

def someotherfunc():
  b = mymodule.myFunction(10)

if __name__ ==...
```

It shall be available in my whole catkin workspace. Where do I have to put it?

Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/70762/workspace-global-python-module---where-to-put?/) by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1145 on 2013-08-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think this tutorial covers what you would like to do:

- http://www.ros.org/wiki/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/Makefile#Installing_scripts_and_exporting_modules

**summary:**

**1.** Create setup.py in your package root directory with these contents (where `<python_mod>` is replaced by the name of your python module, typically the same name as your catkin package)

```
## ! DO NOT MANUALLY INVOKE THIS setup.py, USE CATKIN INSTEAD

from distutils.core import setup
from catkin_pkg.python_setup import generate_distutils_setup

# fetch values from package.xml
setup_args = generate_distutils_setup(
    packages=['<python_mod>'],
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    requires=['std_msgs', 'rospy'])
)

setup(**setup_args)
```

**2.** Add the following line to your CMakeLists.txt

```
catkin_python_setup()
```

**3.** Create a directory for your python scripts (if you have any python executables)

```
mkdir <pkg_root>/scripts
```

**4.** Create a directory for your python modules

```
mkdir <pkg_root>/src/<python_mod>/
```

**5.** Add an empty `__init__.py` to your python module directory

```
touch <pkg_root>/src/<python_mod>/__init__.py
```

**6.** create your python mod

```
touch <pkg_root>/src/<python_mod>/mod1.py
```

**You should now be able to import this module as**

`import python_mod.mod1`

---

Hope that helps!

Reference the [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/Makefile#Installing_scripts_and_exporting_modules) for details.

---

Originally posted by [dPackard](https://answers.ros.org/users/4911/dpackard/) with karma: 115 on 2013-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2013-08-06**:
Yeah, works like a charm! Thanks a lot! :-)